The JW's teach one cannot understand the Bible except through their organization which was formed in the 1870's. How were people saved before1870?
This is verified by the following quotes.
1967 "The Bible cannot be properly understood without Jehovah's visible organization in mind." (Watchtower, Oct 1, 1967, pg. 587)
1965 "He does not impart his holy spirit and understanding and appreciation of his Word apart from his visible organization." (Watchtower, July 1, 1965, pg. 391)
1981 "We all need help to understand the Bible, and we cannot find the scriptural guidance we need outside the 'faithful and discreet slave' organization.'" (Watchtower, February 15, 1981, p.19)

I think a good answer to the other question would sufficiently cover the scope of this question.
